# Async for loop via Asyncio in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have some short code that is built with a for loop to iterate through a list of image URLs and download/save the files. This code works fine, but the list of URLs is too large and would take forever to complete one check at a time.

My goal is to make this a asynchronous for loop in hopes that will speed things up greatly, but I just started writing python to build this and don't know enough to utilize the Asyncio library - can't build out the iterations through **aiter**. How can I get this running?

To summarize: I have a for loop and need to make it asynchronous so it can handle multiple iterations simultaneously (setting up a limit for the amount of async loops would be awesome too).

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import asyncio

df = pd.read_excel(r'filelocation', sheet_name='Sheet2')


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    url = row[0]
    filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    open('filelocation' + filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
    r.close()
```

Comment: Async is still single-threaded. You are most likely looking to use multi-threading which will help speed this up. `open('filelocation' + filename, 'wb').write(r.content)` is also a really bad idea as you never close the file here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on multi-threading and the open... open line. I will look into multi-threading and I add a close for that file: 
`f = open('filelocation' + filename, 'wb')`
`f.write(r.content)`
`f.close()`

Comment: What is your network speed, how fast is the server on the other end, and how large are the files?  If your network is already maxed out, there is no code you can possibly write that will speed it up.  The typical web browser will already download and save files as fast as your network allows.  My advice is not to write any program until you have evaluated your hardware limitations.

Comment: @PaulCornelius I am on 80/25 and my download times are fast enough in general, if I delete the files I downloaded and run again the cached images download in about 0.2-0.4 seconds, but the hangup is just the amount of time it takes to request and download the images and the sequential request performance I can't get past, even when assigning a Pool. New images download at about 1 every second. I think you are definitely right in that you should evaluate what you need before you write a program - python is probably not the way to go here unless I want to divide an conquer with multiple scripts.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  Isn't a cached image already downloaded?  I can write a little Python server that can handle far more than 1 HTTP request per second, so I don't see why making the request should consume so much time.  I find it hard to believe that Python is really limiting you since a lot of the work is being done by the OS anyway. 
 What happens if you download the same image 100 times, or download 100 small files from the same servers, or download the files without writing them to disk?